# How to change letter spacing in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, string, swift, navigation

I'd like to change the letter spacing in the title of my navigation bar but I've had no success so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

A cool extension for UILabel:

```
extension UILabel{
func setCharacterSpacing(_ spacing: CGFloat){
    let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "")
    attributedStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: spacing, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedStr.length))
    self.attributedText = attributedStr
 }
}
```

Usage:

```
label.setCharacterSpacing(4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the title via code passing the title string with some blank spacing ("E x a m p l e"), or with a tab (\t) or via code like this:

```
 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Example")
 attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value:   CGFloat(1.4), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 9))
```

Then you assign attributedString to your title.

Answer (score 2):

the bellow function works for me, hope this helps you too

```
func setCharacterSpacig(string:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

    let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
    attributedStr.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 1.25, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedStr.length))
    return attributedStr
}
```