# How to change letter spacing of UIButton in Swift?

Tags: swift, uibutton, letter-spacing

I've found how to set letter spacing to UILabel ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320056/how-to-change-letter-spacing-in-swift)) but this method is not working for UIButtons. Does anyone know how to do it?

Here is the code i'm using

```
    let buttonString = agreementButton.attributedTitleForState(.Normal) as! NSMutableAttributedString
    buttonString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 1.0, range: NSMakeRange(0, buttonString.length))
    agreementButton.setAttributedTitle(buttonString, forState: .Normal)
```

It throws me an error: `'NSConcreteAttributedString' (0x19e508660) to 'NSMutableAttributedString' (0x19e506a40).`

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Please post the code that is not working for you.

Comment: Updated for you to see the broken code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Make the `NSAttributedString` like in the question you linked
2. Call `setAttributedTitle(_ ,forState:)` on your `UIButton`

---

Try this (untested):

```
let title = agreementButton.titleForState(.Normal)
let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: [NSKernAttributeName: 1.0])
agreementButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: My bad. Should have been just `setAttributedTitle`. Edited

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 5.0**

```
extension UIButton{
   func addTextSpacing(_ spacing: CGFloat){
       let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title(for: .normal) ?? "")
       attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: spacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.string.count))
       self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
   }
}
button.addTextSpacing(1)

extension UILabel{
    func addTextSpacing(_ spacing: CGFloat){
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "")
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: spacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.string.count))
        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
label.addTextSpacing(1)

extension UITextField{
    func addPlaceholderSpacing(_ spacing: CGFloat){
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.placeholder ?? "")
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: spacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.string.count))
        self.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString
    }
}
textField.addPlaceholderSpacing(1)

extension UINavigationItem{
    func addSpacing(_ spacing: CGFloat){
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.title ?? "")
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: spacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.string.count))
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)
        label.attributedText = attributedString
        label.sizeToFit()
        self.titleView = label
    }
}
navigationItem.addSpacing(1)
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**

```
extension UIButton{

    func addTextSpacing(_ letterSpacing: CGFloat){
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (self.titleLabel?.text!)!)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: letterSpacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (self.titleLabel?.text!.count)!))
        self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
    }

}

// Usage: button.addTextSpacing(5.0)
```

Comment: Works great! "NSAttributedStringKey" now should be "NSAttributedString.Key".

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer, but a GOTCHA, and a FIX.

GOTCHA: applying character spacing also adds the space to the END of the text.  This misfeature/bug means that center-aligned text will appear incorrectly.

FIX: when creating a Range for the attributed text, subtract 1 from the text.count value (thus ignoring the last character in the string for spacing purposes.)

e.g. incorrect centering due to extra space:

[image]

fixed:

[image]

[edited]

On a related note, if you are using EdgeInsets to impose padding around the text, your `UIButton` subclass will need to override `intrinsicContentsSize:`

```
override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
    let insets = self.titleEdgeInsets
    let width = size.width + insets.left + insets.right
    let height = size.height + insets.top + insets.bottom
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5** Extension goes here.

```
extension UIButton {
    @IBInspectable
    var letterSpacing: CGFloat {
        set {
            let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString
            if let currentAttrString = attributedTitle(for: .normal) {
                attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: currentAttrString)
            }
            else {
                attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.title(for: .normal) ?? "")
                setTitle(.none, for: .normal)
            }

            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: newValue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
            setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
        }
        get {
            if let currentLetterSpace = attributedTitle(for: .normal)?.attribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, at: 0, effectiveRange: .none) as? CGFloat {
                return currentLetterSpace
            }
            else {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: You can set the letter space on storyboard or by code.

```
button.letterSpacing = 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [Code Different](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538939/code-different) doesn't respect text color settings. Also one could override the UIButton class to have the spacing parameter available even in the storyboard. Here comes an updated Swift 3 solution:

**Swift 3**

```
class UIButtonWithSpacing : UIButton
{
    override func setTitle(_ title: String?, for state: UIControlState)
    {
        if let title = title, spacing != 0
        {
            let color = super.titleColor(for: state) ?? UIColor.black
            let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(
                string: title,
                attributes: [NSKernAttributeName: spacing,
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color])
            super.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: state)
        }
        else
        {
            super.setTitle(title, for: state)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func updateTitleLabel_()
    {
        let states:[UIControlState] = [.normal, .highlighted, .selected, .disabled]
        for state in states
        {
            let currentText = super.title(for: state)
            self.setTitle(currentText, for: state)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var spacing:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            updateTitleLabel_()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for **Swift 4** based off `jaya raj`'s  answer.

```
extension UIButton{
    func addTextSpacing(spacing: CGFloat){
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (self.titleLabel?.text!)!)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: spacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (self.titleLabel?.text!.characters.count)!))
        self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
    }
}

extension UILabel{
    func addTextSpacing(spacing: CGFloat){
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: spacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.text!.characters.count))
        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}

extension UITextField{
    func addPlaceholderSpacing(spacing: CGFloat){
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.placeholder!)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: spacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.placeholder!.characters.count))
        self.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString
    }
}

extension UINavigationItem{
    func addSpacing(spacing: CGFloat){
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.title!)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: spacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.title!.characters.count))
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
        label.attributedText = attributedString
        label.sizeToFit()
        self.titleView = label
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for **Swift 5** without forced unwrapping:

I feel this is a better solution as we cater for existing attributes on the button as well

```
func addTextSpacing(_ letterSpacing: CGFloat) {
    let attributedString = attributedTitle(for: .normal)?.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableAttributedString ??
        NSMutableAttributedString(string: title(for: .normal) ?? "")
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: letterSpacing,
                                  range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.string.count))
    self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
guard let buttonTitle = button.title(for: .normal) else { return }
    
    let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: buttonTitle, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.kern: kernValue])
    button.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: .normal)
```